# Colorir linha do GridView

Tags: vb.net

Esse é meu código:

```
Private Sub ListaVeiculos_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles ListaVeiculos.CellFormatting
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListaVeiculos.Rows.Count - 1
        If ListaVeiculos.Rows(i).Cells(("DateFimVig")).Value.ToString = "19/02/2020" Then
            ListaVeiculos.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Não está funcionando. Não está colorindo nada.

Comment: `ForeColor` muda a cor do texto. Já tentou usar o `BackColor`?

Comment: Já. Não funciona.

Comment: Já verificou se essa condicional está sendo `True` para alterar o valor?

Comment: Coincidentemente esse problema é só com a coluna de data. Quando uso outras colunas com nomes comuns funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.
Vou deixar o código caso alguém precise colorir linhas do *GridView* usando como condição datas:

```
Private Sub ListaVeiculos_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles ListaVeiculos.CellFormatting
    Dim dt As String
    Dim thd, nw As Date

    nw = Date.Now

    nw = nw.AddDays(30)

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListaVeiculos.Rows.Count - 1
        dt = ListaVeiculos.Rows(i).Cells("DateFimVig").Value.ToString

        If dt <> "" Then
            thd = Date.Parse(dt)
        End If

        If thd.Date <= nw.Date Then
            ListaVeiculos.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```